# Benchmarking Apache Ignite Application

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I want to benchmark my **Apache Ignite application** using **Yardstick framework** provided at link
[Yardstick framework](https://github.com/gridgain/yardstick-gridgain)

My application consists of combination of **cache.gets()** and **cache.puts()** which creates **one transaction**. Number of caches involved are also more than one in my application. I want to benchmark this transaction to get transactions/sec and latency for my application. Where can I find help to write java code for same? Standard benchmark drivers provided in yardstick does not involve more than one cache. So how can we write benchmark for more than one cache?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this? Basically, you can implement any login within `BenchmarkDriver`.

Comment: All classes in benchmarkdrivers(e.g. IgnitePutBenchmark, IgniteGetBenchmark etc) extends abstact class **IgniteCacheAbstractBenchmark** which allows to define only one cache with test() function. So how can we extend this benchmark so that it can be used with operation consisting of puts() and gets() involving **any number of caches**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide your own implementation of `BenchmarkDriver` interface which will execute test logic specific for your case. You can use existing implementations for reference.